# What does the court dialect of Infernal sound like?

Tags: forgotten-realms, languages

I would be interested in how I could imagine speaking [infernal-language](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Infernal_language) especially the dialect described as:

> The fourth form of Infernal is the court language of Baator, used only by pit fiends and the archdevils. This form of the language is so utterly corrupt and evil that its malevolence can drag listeners into hateful despair just through hearing its patterns.

I really would love to know how I could at least imagine this to sound to roleplay my warlock perfectly.

Is there any information given by published material, wikis or any other hints?  The source from the wiki talks about it some, but  I have no idea how a language needs to be to achieve the cited restrictions or could even have a "smell" of hatred, or a language that smells at all.

(Faces of Evil: The Fiends. p. 35. ISBN 0-7869-3430-1.)

emphasis mine

> The noises uttered often appear to bear no relation to one another, instead sounding like a combination of **barking hound**, an **eloquent verse**, the **squeal of slate and steel** and the sibtle **smell of hatred**. [...] But in all situations, the sound of the language being used aloud is cause for fright.

But the problem here is, I can't imagine how to roleplay this, without appearing more ridiciouless than inducing hatred.

Answer (score 15):

A sound like "clashing metal" and/or "hatred" self-evidently describes [death metal vocals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_growl).  This is borne out by the [infernal script](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/12/02/infernal-script/)'s obvious affinity for umlauts.

---

The *[Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiendish_Codex_II:_Tyrants_of_the_Nine_Hells)* sourcebook for D&D 3.5e has on page 28 a sidebar "The Infernal Tongue":

> Devils speak and write Infernal, a painfully rigorous language that formed spontaneously on Asmodeus's stern lips when he landed at the bottom of the Pit.  Best pronounced with a forked or wriggling tongue, Infernal uses a mathematically rigid grammar.  Only one correct way exists to construct any given statement in Infernal.  Thus, devils are quick to mock non-native speakers.  Except when in disguise, they find the urge to correct errors in spoken or written infernal nearly impossible to resist.
>
> [...] most unique devils also speak an archaic form of Infernal known as Mabrahoring (High Infernal).  This rarefied tongue is rarely spoken outside the citadels of Baator.  Only unique devils can learn and speak the language.

Comment: I declare my willingness to wear these downvotes until such time as someone else submits a better answer.

Comment: From that death metal link: *"Although the vast majority of death metal bands use very **low, beast-like, almost indiscernible growls** as vocals, many also have **high and screechy or operatic** vocals"*. Sounds pretty close to "barking hound... eloquent verse... squeal of slate and steel" to me! (I still don't know what the smell of hatred sounds like...)